# Can Apache Access Logs be kept separated & also combined as well too?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, virtualhost, log-files

My question may be a bit confusing, and sorry for that. Here is what i need:

Well, i have (let's say) 3 Websites hosted on one Apache (which are defined inside each `VirtualHost` settings. Then i **currently** log their Access Logs separately as in:

- /var/log/httpd/website-a.com.access_log
- /var/log/httpd/website-b.com.access_log
- /var/log/httpd/website-c.com.access_log

So it is all fine. But **at the same time**, i ALSO want them (all the access logs) inside the Apache's default localhost log file *(i'm not sure how to call that one)*. May be:

- /var/log/httpd/access_log *(I think this is default one)*

---

In other words, is there a way to (how to) keep the Access Logs in the separated manner, and at the same time, keep all in the same combined file also?

---

So this will allow me to see each of the Access Logs in their separated files. And at the same time, i can see all the logs in one place also IF I NEED TO.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.  Instead of creating a CustomLog entry in each VirtualHost section, use SetEnvIfNoCase in the global config *httpd.conf* to set a variable if the domain matches and then log that variable enabled entry to a file.

e.g.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host website-a.com weba
SetEnvIfNoCase Host website-b.com webb
SetEnvIfNoCase Host website-c.com webc

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/website-a.com.access_log combined env=weba
```

and so on.  Of course, you will have to account for variations of your domains names, possibly using regex if required should you need to be more specific about sub-domains.

[edit]  You may need to escape the dot in the domain name.